# Application type for excel in html format

Tags: html, excel, web, mime

I want to open html file in excel, if I set mime type to application/vnd.ms-excel it adds .xls extension to the file and excel gives warning that the file is in different format that the extension.
Is there a way to still open it in excel but without warning and with the right extension?

P.S. Basically my question is if there is a way to say something like this:

```
header.setContentType("html/text");
header.setProgramToOpenFile("excel");
```

Comment: "Extension hardening" was added to Office applications to warn the user when the file format doesn't match the file extension. I'm guessing maybe you're sending HTML data to the client with an xls extension? That will trigger the warning.  If you want that not to happen, you have to send an actual Excel-format file (not HTML content pretending to be Excel).  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Comment: You are correct that the extension is different from the content of the file, I was wondering though if there is a way to specify the extension separately from the application that you want this file to opened with.

Comment: The warning is there to guard against possible malicious files: there's nothing you can do from the server-side other than send a file of the "correct" format.

Comment: But warning is only there for files that have content that's different from what extension implies. If extension and content are the same there is no warning. E.g. if I try to open .html file with excel it won't give me warning if it's html file inside.

Comment: If you label your response type as HTML then it's going to open in the browser, since that's the default handler for HTML content.  Is this omsthing you want to do only for yourself (ie. you have some control over the client) or is this for other users (where you have no control)? If it's not just for yourself then I'm not sure it's do-able.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the html file and select 'open with'. This will present you with options, click 'Choose default program...' if Excel is not shown. This will bring up the Open with dialogue box. Deselect the check box 'Always use the selected...' if you don't want every html file on your system to open with Excel.

If Excel is in the list shown in this dialogue you can select it from there. If not click on 'Browse...' and then find your Excel application, on my system the path is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE

But it may well be different on yours depending on your version of office etc.

Once you have found it, this should open the html file in Excel for you.

**EDIT**

A note of caution: If you edit the html file while in Excel it changes the file significantly (i.e. the code behind it changes and it looks different in a web browser), so I would suggest taking a backup first in case you are not happy with the results.

Comment: I am looking for programmatic solution - what header do I need to set in HTML so users don't need to do any of the things you described, just click on open and it opens without warning

Comment: I'm not sure if what you are suggesting is possible as what you are trying to change is the behaviour of the operating system. I have done a quick search but not found anything that looks like what you are asking for. This (http://www.glump.net/howto/web/serve-html-as-an-excel-file-from-a-web-application) is the closest I could find, this is actually changing the file extension as well, but may be worth trying this without altering the extension?